# Automate PowerShell Response to prompt

Tags: powershell, read-host

Creating a PowerShell script that calls an apps cmdlet.  When then cmdlet runs it prompts for a response and the scripts hangs.  The cmdlet doesn't have any parameters for this.  Is there any way to respond programmatically? I tried ECHO but that doesn't work.

[image: script hanging]

Comment: Without seeing the `*assessment.ps1` script, unable to check if you can pass params to it.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get PowerShell scripts that solicit input via the host - typically, via `Read-Host` - to **read input from the *pipeline* instead of from the *keyboard*** is to use to **run the script as an *external* PowerShell instance**.

A simple example:

```
# Does NOT work: pipeline input is IGNORED and Read-Host "hangs", i.e.,
# it waits for interactive input.
'y' | & { Read-Host "Y/N?" }


# OK: By launching the command via a new PowerShell instance,
#     Read-Host reads from the pipeline (stdin).
#     To run a script file externally, use -file instead of -command.
'y' | powershell -noprofile -command 'Read-Host "Y/N?"'
```

Note: Running the script / command via an external PowerShell instance comes at a cost:

- Creating a new PowerShell process is costly in terms of performance.
- Output from the new instance will be *textual* (strings) by default, not *objects*.

  - You can *approximate* the usual in-process experience by passing `-OutputFormat xml` to the external instance and post-processing the results via `Import-CliXml`, but that has limitations.