# Windows Forms SendKeys using Read-Host

Tags: powershell, scripting

Apologies if this question has already been answered on another thread, but I went looking for my specific query and I couldn't anything.

The issue I have is sending keystrokes to a Read-Host command. When I do this, nothing populates. Is this even possible?

```
$sendKeys = [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]
Sleep-Start -Seconds 1
$sendKeys::SendWait('serv01{ENTER}')
Read-Host -Prompt "Server Name"
```

Running this would only show the prompt and still waiting for input:

```
Server Name:
```

Please advise if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

- DOES work in regular console windows, in Windows Terminal, and - assuming the keyboard focus is on the integrated terminal when the code is run - in Visual Studio Code.
- does NOT work in the Windows PowerShell ISE.

  - However, given that the ISE is [obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support), consider migrating to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).
  - As a *workaround*, consider the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65615466/45375), which uses a custom `Read-Host` function that returns predefined responses.

Note: The workaround suggested for use in the ISE may actually be the preferable solution overall, given that sending keystrokes is inherently brittle (not fully robust).