# Call PowerShell script PS1 from another PS1 AND then automate user input

Tags: powershell

I have two scripts:

**Script1** and **Script2**

**Script1** contains:

```
$Title = "bullshit"
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $Title    

$Name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your  name'
Write-Host "Your name is '$Name'"
```

**Script2** contains:

```
./Script1.ps1
```

What I need is to run Script2, which will run Script1, and once that script asks for user input, Script2 would just press enter, and let it continue.

I tried solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849522/how-to-perform-keystroke-inside-powershell), but it doesn´t work - it keeps waiting for user input, and only after you manually press enter, it will produce keypress (enter).

Other proposed solution for Script2 I found has the same problem as the aforementioned one:

```
./Script1.ps1

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('bullshit')
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('myPassword{ENTER}')
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong?
How can I make the Script2 press enter, once Script1 asks for it?

Comment: Try double quotes instead of single quotes : "myPassword{ENTER}"

Comment: Would putting `./Script1.ps1` beneath `$wshell.SendKeys('myPassword{ENTER}')` work for you? Just tested and it does send input. You just need to call the script after the rest of the code.

Comment: @jdweng, There is _no_ difference between `'myPassword{ENTER}'`  and `"myPassword{ENTER}"`, given that the string content contains no `$` symbols that would be subject to string expansion (interpolation) in `"..."` strings. Your comment is not only irrelevant to the question at hand and therefore a distraction, it is a _confusing_ distraction.

Comment: @mklement0 : Isn't {Enter} a keyboard entry that needs to be replaced?

Comment: @jdweng, `{ENTER}` is _unrelated to PowerShell's string expansion_ (which, as noted, only acts on `$`-prefixed tokens). It is part of the syntax understood by `.SendKeys()` and must therefore be _passed through to it_, as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***immediate* answer to your question** is that **you need to run your keystroke-sending code *in parallel*** to your `./Script1.ps1` invocation, given that `./Script.ps1` is a *synchronous call* whose `Read-Host` call blocks further processing until a response has been provided.

However, as [kconsiglio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20473839/kconsiglio) points, in your simple case it **may be sufficient to simply send the keystrokes *ahead* of time**, relying on them to be buffered and later read by `Read-Host`, which doesn't require parallelism:

```bash
# Send the keystrokes and rely on their getting buffered, 
# so that the subsequently launched ./Script.ps1 reads them.
(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys('myPassword{ENTER}')  

./Script.ps1
```

You may need parallelism for more sophisticated interaction with the interactive script, in which case you can use [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) or, preferably, [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) (available *by default* in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), *installable on demand* in *Windows PowerShell*) for this parallel execution:

```bash
$Title = "bullshit"
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $Title    

# Launch the keystroke-sending code in parallel, in the background.
# Note: If Start-ThreadJob is available / installed, use it instead.
$jb = Start-Job {
  $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
  $wshell.AppActivate('bullshit')
  Sleep 1
  $wshell.SendKeys('myPassword{ENTER}')  
}

$Name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your  name'
Write-Host "Your name is '$Name'" 

Remove-Job -Force $jb
```

---

However, **sending keystrokes is always *brittle* (can break)**, isn't always an option (e.g., in hidden scheduled tasks), and is **best avoided if *robust alternatives* are available**:

You **can automate input to [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host)** in one of two ways:

- **Call the target script via the *PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)***, in which case `Read-Host` responses can be provided *via the pipeline (stdin)* - notably, this does *not* work in-session:

  ```bash
  # Note: Use 'pwsh.exe' if you're running PowerShell (Core) 7+
  'myPassword' | powershell.exe -File ./Script.ps1
  ```

  - The potential down-side (apart from a performance hit due to launching another PowerShell instance) is that *output* from `./Script.ps1` will be *text* only.
- **Define a *proxy* `Read-Host` function** that overrides the built-in cmdlet and automatically returns the desired string instead of prompting:

  ```bash
   function Read-Host { 'mypassword' }
   ./Script.ps1
   Remove-Item function:Read-Host
  ```

  - This technique was borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65615466/45375), which also shows how to make the automated responses *conditional* based on the *prompt string*.
  - The advantage is *in-process* execution, with *preservation of type fidelity* in the script's output.
  - Note that you only need to return the actual desired response, such as `'mypassword'` - there is *no* simulation of keystrokes involved here, and therefore *no* need for key specifiers such as `{ENTER}` (which only the `.SendKeys()` method would understand).

Comment: Thank you for the exhausting answer :)
kconsiglio´s solution worked, but I would like to utilize the **Define proxy** solution, because of the advantages you mentioned.

I have one problem with it though: When I try to apply it:
`function Read-Host { '{ENTER}' }
./Script1.ps1
Remove-Item function:Read-Host`

What happens is it will send the enter as a string, instead of interpreting it as "hit the enter key."

So the output looks like this: 
`Your name is '{ENTER}'`

instead of this:
`Your name is ''`

Comment: I tried it with both variants:
`function Read-Host { '{ENTER}' } / function Read-Host { '~' }`

Comment: Found it!
The solution was to use dollar sign:
`function Read-Host { "${ENTER}" }`

Comment: @Blu3Rat, `"${ENTER}"` is the same as `''`, i.e. the _empty string_ (unless you define an `$ENTER` == `${ENTER}` variable first), thanks to PowerShell's string interpolation. That is, all you need is `function Read-Host { '' }` in order to get the equivalent of just pressing ENTER in a real `Read-Host` call, thereby returning the empty string. There is no sending of keystrokes involved here (`{ENTER}` is syntax only understood by `.SendKeys()`). I've also updated the answer to make that clearer.